# Gantt Chart - Project Task - Can Not Edit Item (Row)

Tags: tasks, gantt-view

I have created a Project Task List (aka the one with the Gantt Chart) and we are having a problem because no one can edit anything. I have reviewed all the permissions and I can't find anything wrong. I have full control permissions on the list and still I get nothing but that grayed out box saying it is disabled. Anyone got any ideas on how to allow edits to that row of my project task table?[image]

Comment: how were you able to display the 'person or group' field in gantt chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it figured out. You have to enable the edit column on the project task list. The "edit item" button isn't an option at any time for this list. Instead you add the "edit item" column on the list and it will give you a pencil icon in that column for each entry.

Here is a walk through of how to fix it with screen shots if you need more information on adding the column.

http://ryandunn.co/sharepoint-not-able-to-edit-items-in-a-project-task-gantt-chart[image]

Answer (score 1):

I prefer editing in the Default Edit Form. 
The best way to edit that way is to go to another view like (All Tasks, My Tasks, etc.)
[image]

click on the editable link (Title)

[image]

Clock on the Edit Form button.

[image]

Then you will get the form that looks a lot like the Default New Item

[image]